# Получение всех IP-адресов заданной подсети

Tags: ip, awk, grep

Как получить все IP-адреса имеющиеся в подсетях исходной системы и отвечающие на UDP запросы? Те на выходе ожидается файл, каждая строка которого это IP-адрес.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен nmap

Например, у нас сеть 192.168.1.255

Как указали в ответе ниже (не могу комментировать пока, увы), делаем

nmap -sU -n -v '192.168.1.*'

и радуемся!

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к Nmap подскажу, что можно воспользоваться следующей командой

```
nmap -sU -n -v host-range
```

Либо брать откуда-то список хостов.

Answer (score 0):

Надо сделать нечто подобное:

```
ifconfig -a | grep 'inet '.[^2] | awk '{print $2}'﻿
```

Это для Соляриса.

Answer (score 0):

Еще есть NetView и xSpider

Comment: NetView > работает только в среде Windows NT, 2000, XPxSpider > Работает под управлением Windows 2000/XP/2003/Vista/7Теги [awk](http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/tagged/awk/), [grep](http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/tagged/grep/), кажется не были присущи платформам Windows. Посему, думаю, что не катит.